# cameraOverlayView from xib

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been searching for a while and can not seem to find a clear way of doing this. Any link I did find is outdated. I am presenting a camera like so

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    //Get the camera
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:self.imagePicker.sourceType];
    self.imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; //<-- This does not work in iOS7


    //set our custom overlay view


    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

}
```

I have a ViewController connected to an xib named `ControllsViewController` . I have no idea how to assign it to `self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView =` . Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `ControllsViewController` using the xib. Assuming you have a xib file called "ControllsViewController" in your main bundle:

```
ControllsViewController *overlayViewController = [ControllsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ControllsViewController" bundle:nil];
self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayViewController.view;
```

You probably want to assign overlayViewController to a property to keep it around.

Comment: This worked perfect!! I wasted hours trying to get this done. Thanks. Do you know any resources for making the buttons in the new view take the photo?

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` has an instance method `takePicture` which you can use to take a picture. The only thing left to do is hook it up to the `ControllsViewController`. You can do this using a property on the `ControllsViewController`, or do it using delegation via your main view controller.